# Solution on a complex sub select query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, index, subquery

I created a SQL query that requires me to pull data from 2 separate databases, and I noticed that what I did is this:

```
Select 
    *,
    (Select Z.f From DatabaseZ.TblZ Z where Z.w = A.w) as valueZA,
    (Select Z.k From DatabaseZ.TblZ Z where Z.w = A.w) as valueZB,
From 
    DatabaseA.TblA A 
LEFT JOIN 
    DatabaseA.TblB B A.x = B.x
where 
    A.isActiveBit = '1';
```

The problem I encounter is that the query is slow, due to the fact that `Databasez.TblZ` contains about 200K records,and that there is new data every 30 minutes. I think that using a subquery here is the main issue, since DatabaseA.TblA also contains a lot of records, the database is already expending a lot of memory and computing power just for the external query, and it takes more time since the subquery also takes a while.

My question is how can I speed up the query, should I change the way I use my sub queries? 
I am currently thinking of running the query without the subqueries, then do this:

```
//PHP Code, just a sample not actual code

//$queryResult is the result of my first query

$subqueryArray = array();

//I make a loop depending on the number of records I got
for($x=0;$x <count($queryResult);$x++)
{
$subqueryArray[] = $this->Main->query("select X.f from Databasez.TblZ Z where ",$queryResult['w']);
//w because it's the field name in the previous query, I'll also do the same for the other subquery
}
```

I am not sure if the solution I am thinking of is appropriate, since I think the query would take longer if I do it this way. I am also thinking of using indexes but I think that wont make any significant impact on my speed(I am still fairly new with databases) since I need to finish the entire query within 3 seconds(already giving it a lot of time). My current query currently runs at 37 seconds.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can remove multiple references of the same table:

```
Select A.w,
    oa.f as valueZA,
    oa.k as valueZB,
From DatabaseA.TblA A 
    LEFT JOIN DatabaseA.TblB B A.x = B.x
    outer apply (
        Select Z.f, Z.k From DatabaseZ.TblZ Z where Z.w = A.w
    ) oa
where A.isActiveBit = '1';
```

You can replace `outer` with `cross`, depending on the logic you need.

Also, looking for index suggestions from SQL Server definitely wouldn't hurt. Either check execution plan suggestions, or even better, google for diagnostic scripts referring `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats()` DMV.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Roger's answer, would be to `LEFT JOIN` to `TblZ`. Personally I think for the example you've posted, an `APPLY` is probably not the most appropriate method of data retrieval, however it would be worth testing performance against the `APPLY` to see which is quicker.

I'd also recommend not selecting `*`, simply because you could be pulling columns that are not needed and causing sub-optimal indexes to be used.

```
   SELECT A.*, B.*,
      Z.f as valueZA,
      Z.k as valueZB,
    FROM DatabaseA.TblA A 
    LEFT JOIN DatabaseA.TblB B ON A.x = B.x
    LEFT JOIN DatabaseZ.TblZ Z ON Z.w = A.w
    WHERE A.isActiveBit = '1';
```

I'd also recommend looking at implementing an index on `TblZ.w` that includes `f` and `k`, but it would be best to see what indexes you currently have.